# Gradle build fails because the tests using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, resttemplate, endpoint

I have an Spring Boot application. It has some endpoints, and i would like to test them using RestTemplate. The test's are working fine.. if the app is running I just need to Run the Test class.. and all the tests are passed. But actually if I using 'gradle clean build' all the tests are failing because of Connection refused... obviously cause the app trying to call itself..but it is not running on any port.

Here's one of my @Test, where BASE_URL is https://localhost:8080/.

```
@Test
   public void receiveFiscalMessages_one_valid_request() {
       DEFAULT_REQUEST = RequestGenerator.getDefaultRequest_validRequestMessage();

       Response response = client.postMessages(BASE_URL + "test", DEFAULT_REQUEST).getBody();
       ...
   }
```

And this is the client:

```
public ResponseEntity<Response> postMessages(String url, String request) {
       HttpEntity<String> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request);

       return restTemplate.exchange(
               url,
               HttpMethod.POST,
               requestHttpEntity,
               new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response>() {
               });
   }
```

The best would be if I don't need to use 'gradle clean build -x test' in the future. I would like to see my tests passing on build as well, not just if i run the application, and after if i run the test class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and `@LocalServerPort`. refer to [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server)

Comment: I'm still getting ConnactionException :/

Comment: am I need to use TestRestTemplate instead of RestTemplate in this case? O.o